# difference of web forms SITE and web form APPLICATION in vs studio 2012 for web

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web

I can't decide what to choose between web forms SITE and web form APPLICATION.

in VS 2012 for web, i can choose:

ASP.net Web Forms Application, by going to File>New Project. while the other one is
ASP.net Web Forms Site, by File>New Website,

im new in asp.net and im lost, i hope someone will clarify this for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic difference between `Website Project` and `Web Application` is that in a `Website Project` each `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` file is compiled in to its own assembly the first time the page is accessed and in `Web Applications` all the `.aspx` and `.aspx.cs` files are compiled to a single assembly (DLL file) at compile time.

In my experience, `Web Applications` are more geared twards modern web technologies and modern features of the `.Net Framework` and `C#` like `Entity Framework`, `MVC` and `Web Api` (if you decide to integrate any of these in to your project. This is not to say that you cannot use these in a `Website Project`, but this creates all kinds of artifacts.

For new applications I would recommend going for a `Web Application`, in case you want to integrate any newer modules in to your application at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

Differences on the MSDN for study:

[[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx#summary_of_differences][1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#summary_of_differences%5d%5b1%5d)

Comment: Thanks! it answered my question, it clarified me.